# TextArea / <Pre> unable to submit certain character to server

Tags: php, html

Message I send

```
message:!!@@##$$%%ˆˆ&&**(())__++
```

When i do a VarDump

```
"!!@@##$$%%ˆˆ&&**(())__++"
```

3rd Party Server returns

```
"message": "!!@@##$$%%ˆˆ"
```

I'm using FORM and Pre tag in HTML to do a form post. I still cant get why i cant display certain characters. Am i missing some kind of encoding that prevents the 3rd party server from understanding?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the server you are sending the `POST` to, it's impossible to be completely sure - but I would suggest that it's processing your message under its own rules to remove the missing characters for some security reasons. Perhaps you should ask the server's owners?

Comment: The && symbols are the delimiter when sending a GET request, either change your form to submit via POST or make sure your data is fully urlencoded ready for submitting.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins , if i submit using their website normal chat, it will go through. So obviously it isnt some kind of removal of certain characters